# Case or If in where Condition in SYBASE ASE

Tags: sap-ase

I have 3 tables which I am joining in which 2 tables i am cross joining.

The problem is all are inner join, but some time 1 condition can come NULL 
so I wanna put 1 NULL and 2nd value.
pls see the query

`

```
select 
cr.id
, cm.orgaparty_uri
, cm.role_uri
, am.orgaparty_uri
, am.role_uri
, gu.name_t
, gu1.name_t
from 
cdm_clientrelation cr
,cdm_commercial_roles cm
,cdm_commercial_roles am
,gcl_user gu
,gcl_user gu1
where
cm.agreement_uri ='cdm:clientRelation/'+cr.id
and  cm.role_uri ='gcl:role/CommercialManager'
and cm.orgaparty_uri= 'gcl:user/'+gu.id 
AND am.agreement_uri='cdm:clientRelation/'+cr.id
AND am.role_uri='gcl:role/AdministrativeManager'
AND am.orgaparty_uri = 'gcl:user/'+gu1.id`
```

some time Might be possible that either  one of the row is not there in cdm_commercial_roles table for Commercial or Admin Role . so it wont get it and inner join fail
but I need if the Row is not there it will give as NULL as my select Statement 
name
awaiting for ur reply

Comment: My suggestion is not to use the old style join syntax and use the more modern inner and outer join syntax - I assume the ASE supports this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lines to be shown when isn't a correspondence between all tables you can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to solve your problem.

---

> The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and
>   B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the
>   join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table
>   (B). This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in B,
>   the join will still return a row in the result—but with NULL in each
>   column from B. This means that a left outer join returns all the
>   values from the left table, plus matched values from the right table
>   (or NULL in case of no matching join predicate). If the right table
>   returns one row and the left table returns more than one matching row
>   for it, the values in the right table will be repeated for each
>   distinct row on the left table. From Oracle 9i onwards the LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN statement can be used as well as (+).